# I Need to get questions and answer which is in my list of maps ad others made of class and constructor

Tags: flutter, list, maps

I Need to get questions and answer in listview builder which is in my list of maps ad others made of class and constructor . please help me to find out

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: examlist.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      title: Text(
                        examlist[index].title,
    
                        **//HERE I NEED TO PUT QUESTIONS
                        //HERE I NEED TO PUT ANSWERS**
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        examlist[index].desc, 
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
```

**This is my list** which have description and title and question and answers according to class and constructor

```
List<Examlist> examlist = [
        Examlist(
            title: 'G.C.E A/L E-Tech Tamil - 2022',
            desc:
                'GCE A/L ICT  Unit Exam Papers Tamil Medium 2020  (New Syllabus). You can download using the following link Below. It’s free to download.',
            quesans: [
              {
                'question':
                    'Confidence intervals are useful when trying to estimate',
                'answer': 'unknown parameters',
              }
            ]),
        Examlist(
            title: 'G.C.E O/L Islam Tamil - 2022',
            desc:
                'GCE A/L ICT  Unit Exam Papers Tamil Medium 2020  (New Syllabus). You can download using the following link Below. It’s free to download.',
            quesans: [
              {
                'question':
                    'Confidence intervals are useful when trying to estimate',
                'answer': 'unknown parameters',
              }
            ]),
      ];
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick anwser

```
 ListView.builder(
                itemCount: examlist.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final questionsList = examlist[index].quesans;
                  
                  for (var i = 0; i < questionsList.length; i++) {
                    q = questionsList[question];
                    a = questionsList[answer];
                    // you can get each question and answer here 
                    //but this bad decision. 
                    // you should move this to model or controller if you want
                  }
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      title: Text(
                        examlist[index].title,
    
                        **//HERE I NEED TO PUT QUESTIONS
                        //HERE I NEED TO PUT ANSWERS**
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        examlist[index].desc, 
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
```

Comment: it says undefined name 'questions'